# Using JAGS to Estimate median canopy cover with binomial and 20 samples/plot

Tags: r, jags, binomial-cdf

I would like to estimate medians as well as 5, 25, 75, and 95th percentiles of canopy cover for 13 groups (recorded as the number of points out of 20 with vegetation present or not) and 223 samples total. I previously posted this assuming a beta distribution but that was incorrect. This is for a manuscript that is overdue and this is the last piece that is missing. I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me to completion (just until the code works). I think I'm close it just needs some tweaking - I think.

(I went in to edit to fix two down votes but I'm not sure what isn't clear).

MANY MANY THANKS!

Below is my model statement, the R code and data. As is, the error I get is

```
model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 16.
Subset out of range: re[14]
```

But please note that I removed spaces below and the error refers to the likelihood statement.

```
model{
# priors
for (i in 1:13){
 alpha[i] ~ dunif(0, 1)
 re[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
}
#likelihood
for (i in 1:223) {
   canopy[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 20)
   logit(p[i]) <- alpha[site[i]] + re[i] 
}   
 median <- 1/(1+exp(alpha[site[i]]))
t4est1_100  <- step(median[1]-median[4])
t5est1_10 <- step(median[3]-median[4])
t6est10_100 <- step(median[2]-median[3])

}
```

The R code:

```
cover <- read.csv("f:\\brazil\\canopy2.csv", header=T)
library(R2jags)
library(rjags)
setwd("f://brazil")
site <- frag$site
canopy <- frag$canopy*20
N <- length(frag$site)

jags.data <- list("site", "canopy")
jags.params <- c("median", "test100MF","test100MT","test100fc","test100fa", 
"test100gv","test100hm","test100mc", "test100ca","test100ct", "test10MF",
"test10MT", "test10fc","test10fa", "test10gv", "test10hm", "test10mc", "test10ca", 
"test10ct", "test1MF", "test1MT", "test1fc",  "test1fa",  "test1gv", "test1hm", 
"test1mc", "test1ca", "test1ct", "t1est1_con","t2est10_con","t3est100_con",
"t4est1_100","t5est1_10","t6est10_100")
#inits1 <- list(a=0, sd=0)
#inits2 <- list(a=100, sd=50)
#jags.inits <- list(inits1, inits2)

jags.inits <- function() {
  list(alpha = 0, re=0)}

jagsfit2 <- jags(data=jags.data, inits=jags.inits, jags.params,
n.iter=1000000, n.burnin=20000, model.file="fragmodelbinom.txt")
my.coda <- as.mcmc(jagsfit2)
summary(my.coda, quantiles=c(0.05, 0.25,0.5,0.75, 0.95))
print(jagsfit2, digits=3)
```

The data:

```
structure(list(site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L
), canopy = c(0, 0.05, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.05, 0.2, 
0.25, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 
0.45, 0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.55, 0.7, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.9, 1, 1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.35, 0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 
0.65, 0.7, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.05, 0.4, 0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.7, 0.85, 0.95, 
1, 1, 1, 0.35, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.65, 0.65, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.85, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.85, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.75, 0.1, 0.35, 
0.6, 1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.55, 0.65, 0.65, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.95, 0.95, 1)), .Names = c("site", "canopy"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -227L))
```

Comment: Maybe you want `logit(p[i]) <- alpha[site[i]] + re[site[i]]`

Comment: Thanks John. That does make perfect sense. Still having issues though (see below). Great blog!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two obvious mistakes by reading your code. In the model definition you have:

```
    for (i in 1:223) {
     canopy[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 20)
     logit(p[i]) <- alpha[site[i]] + re[i] 
    }
```

The above can't be right, since the `re` parameter has just 13 components, as you have defined it. I guess it should be `re[site[i]]` instead. This is the cause of the error you are getting.

The second is the line `median <- 1/(1+exp(alpha[site[i]]))`: it is outside any for loop, while I guess it should be inside, since it depends on `i`.

Comment: Oh yea, that does make sense. I moved median <- ... to the first loop (since I just need the median of each group). And I changed re[i] to re[site[i] but I had this error "Dimension mismatch in values supplied for alpha".  So I changed alpha = 0 to alpha=c(0,0,0...) for 13 0s (one for each group, right)?  Now I have this error: "Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  Error in node canopy[6]
Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization." Changed the 0s and 1s and have the same error. Help please.

Comment: I guess `median` should be in the second loop, since it contains `site` that has length 223 (instead of 13). Another issue I overlooked is that you define `median` as a scalar (length 1) and then try to extract its elements 2,3 and 4. I don't get why you are passing any value at all to `alpha`. Shouldn't they be what you are estimating?

Answer (score 0):

In JAGS, `dbin` takes a probability of success and a number of trials, and returns an integer indicating the number of successes. In your model, you are specifying that the outcomes of `dbin` are your `canopy` values, which all lie between 0 and 1 - this is incorrect.

Why do you specify 20 trials? Are there twenty points at which you evaluated presence/absence of the species? If so, perhaps you should specify your data model as:

```
y[i] ~ dbin(cover[i], 20)
```

where `y[i]` is an integer giving the number of presences of the species at site `i` (these are your data), and `cover` is the thing we're trying to estimate, i.e. the proportional cover of the species recorded as observation `i`). ([Fukaya *et al.* (2010)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/enhanced/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2010.01727.x/#ss2) provide code for a similar problem, where they estimate the probability of barnacle occurrence at survey plots - could be worth a read.)

Here's an example, using simulated data that represents your problem (or at least my understanding of it), which will compile and for which JAGS estimates reasonably accurate cover values.

```
M <- function() {
  for (j in 1:13){
    alpha[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
  }

  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    y[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 20)
    logit(p[i]) <- alpha[site[i]] + eps[i]
    eps[i] ~ dnorm(0, sd^-2)
  }   
  sd ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
```

Note that I've used a vague normal prior for `alpha`, rather than your Uniform(0, 1) prior, since `alpha` is on the logit scale and so isn't bounded by 0 and 1. I've renamed `re` to `eps` for clarity and moved it to the observation level loop.

```
site <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
          1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
          2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
          3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
          3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
          4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
          5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
          7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
          8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
          11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
          13, 13, 13, 13, 13)

set.seed(1)
alpha <- rnorm(13) # 13 independent random site intercepts
sd <- 0.123        # a constant variance for obs around alphas
logit.p <- rnorm(length(site), alpha[site], sd) # logit probs
y <- sapply(plogis(logit.p), rbinom, n=1, size=20)
```

A couple of plots to show the data that we've simulated:

```
plot(plogis(logit.p) ~ site, pch=20, las=1, ylab='p', ylim=c(0, 1))
```

[image]

```
plot(y ~ jitter(site), pch=20, las=1, xlab='site')
```

[image]

```
fit <- jags(list(y=y, site=site), NULL, c('sd', 'alpha', 'p'), M, 3, 1000)
```

Comparing our true `p` to the JAGS estimates:

```
plot(plogis(logit.p), fit$BUGSoutput$summary[
  grep('^p\\[', row.names(fit$BUGSoutput$summary)), '50%'], pch=20,
  xlab='True p', ylab='Estimated p (median and 95% CrI)', las=1, ylim=c(0, 1),
  panel.first=abline(0, 1, lwd=3, col='light gray'))
segments(plogis(logit.p), 
         fit$BUGSoutput$summary[
           grep('^p\\[', row.names(fit$BUGSoutput$summary)), '2.5%'], 
         y1=fit$BUGSoutput$summary[
           grep('^p\\[', row.names(fit$BUGSoutput$summary)), '97.5%'])
```

[image]

And alpha:

```
plot(alpha, fit$BUGSoutput$summary[
  grep('^alpha\\[', row.names(fit$BUGSoutput$summary)), '50%'], pch=20,
  xlab='True alpha', ylab='Estimated alpha (median +95% CrI)', las=1, 
  ylim=c(-1.5, 2.5), panel.first=abline(0, 1, lwd=3, col='light gray'))
segments(alpha, 
         fit$BUGSoutput$summary[
           grep('^alpha\\[', row.names(fit$BUGSoutput$summary)), '2.5%'], 
         y1=fit$BUGSoutput$summary[
           grep('^alpha\\[', row.names(fit$BUGSoutput$summary)), '97.5%'])
```

[image]

Summaries (e.g. quantiles) are easily extracted from the stored samples, and some of these are already presented in the JAGS summary (i.e. `fit$BUGSoutput$summary`). In your case, you are probably interested in the quantiles for the estimates of `alpha` (i.e. mean site cover). Another way to access these, and which is useful when you want quantiles not already calculated by `R2jags`, is as follows:

```
apply(fit$BUGSoutput$sims.list$alpha, 2, quantile, c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8))

#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]     [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]
# 20% -0.6753085 0.08214699 -0.8994924 1.213293 0.2411191 -0.9441959 0.4038927
# 50% -0.6151128 0.15716925 -0.8299434 1.310542 0.3214097 -0.8205142 0.4909790
# 80% -0.5461859 0.23436643 -0.7632734 1.405498 0.3994087 -0.6982591 0.5887423
#          [,8]      [,9]       [,10]    [,11]     [,12]      [,13]
# 20% 0.6052447 0.6722630 -0.46050504 1.513086 0.2352861 -0.6516170
# 50% 0.6971180 0.8914973 -0.24458871 1.677613 0.4217723 -0.5443512
# 80% 0.7858756 1.1142837 -0.01018129 1.839783 0.6183198 -0.4309478
```

You might want to consider a hierarchical approach, though, whereby `alpha` are drawn from a population of alphas that belong to a common distribution. This would involve something like:

```
M <- function() {
  for (j in 1:13){
    alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mean.alpha, sd.alpha^-2)
  }

  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    y[i] ~ dbin(p[i], 20)
    logit(p[i]) <- alpha[site[i]] + eps[i]
    eps[i] ~ dnorm(0, sd^-2)
  }   
  sd ~ dunif(0, 100)
  mean.alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
  sd.alpha ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
```

This would then tell you something about the variance amongst sites in group means (i.e. by inspecting `sd.alpha`). You might also consider allowing `sd` (i.e. the variance amongst observations within sites) to vary across sites, though you might have too few data to do so (and maybe it's completely sensible to have a single, constant `sd` anyway... depends on the system).

Comment: So the idea is to quantify the canopy cover of four habitats (continuous forest, 100-ha, 10-ha and 1-ha forest fragments) with sites used by birds. The 20 subsamples are within each sample. So I note the p/a of vegetation (over 20 m above the ground) at 20 random points within a sample then I just report the proportion in that sample. Does that make sense? I would just report means but I know the estimates must be >0 and <1.